# Response compression for specific actions in .NET 8

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-8

I'm upgrading the platform version of my app from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 8. I came across an issue when I was trying to add filter which compresses the output. That's how it looks like in .NET Framework 4.8:

```
public class CompressAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var encodingsAccepted = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encodingsAccepted))
            return;
    
        encodingsAccepted = encodingsAccepted.ToUpperInvariant();
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
    
        if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("DEFLATE"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
            response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionLevel.Fastest);
    
        }
        else if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("GZIP"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
            response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
    }
}
```

And that's how I modified it:

```
public class CompressAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var encodingsAccepted = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.FirstOrDefault()?.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encodingsAccepted))
            return;

        encodingsAccepted = encodingsAccepted.ToUpperInvariant();
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("DEFLATE"))
        {
            response.Headers.ContentEncoding = "deflate";
            response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionLevel.Fastest);

        }
        else if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("GZIP"))
        {
            response.Headers.ContentEncoding = "gzip";
            response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
    }
}
```

Aaaand there's an error: HttpResponse doesn't contatin a definition for `Filter` property. What should I do to achieve the same functionality as before?

Comment: You need to do this with the help of middleware. You will probably want to use package named `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression`.

Comment: [Response compression in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Comment: So there is no way to implement it in an attribute-like style, only using middleware?

Comment: Response compression in ASP.NET was performed through IIS, not custom filters. In any case .NET 8 is .NET *Core* 8 and ASP.NET Core is a complete rewrite. The pipeline itself is different, the way HttpContext works is different

Comment: @Slepoyi what does it matter how you specify the compression operation? It's still middleware. What's the *real* question behind this? Use different compression options for different controllers? Is that why you didn't use IIS compression to begin with?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm asking because I could use the .NET Framework's compression like `[Compress]` attribute against specific controller actions while in the 'modern' approach the response will be compressed for all existing actions.

Comment: The duplicate shows how to do this, using a custom attribute derived from MiddlewareFilterAttribute. That question's title, `Route specific response compression in dotnet core 2 asp .net? ` asks for the actual problem so it's a lot easier to find. In fact, I found it by googling for `asp.net core response compression per controller` once I suspected that's what you really wanted

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure middleware for that.
[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-8.) is proper example based on package named `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression` that you will probably want to use.